# Debugging ojdbc6-11.2.0.3

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working with Oracle Wallet integration with Java/Spring application. There are some errors happening which I need to debug inside ojdbc6-11.2.0.0 jar. Do we have a way to attach the source of that jar to debug or anyway for debugging ojdbc?

I understand that decompile can be an option but I would like to hear here any better way to do it.

Please advice.
Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the sources? Are the sources freely available? Are you sure you need to debug inside the driver and it's not just your code that's buggy and you misread the stacktrace?

Comment: I don't have source of ojdbc6-11.2.0.3. Yes I need to debug inside the driver.

Comment: Okay, then get the sources. I don't believe you really need to debug inside the driver, but of course it's also interesting to see how the internals work.

Answer (score 1):

There is the debug jar (ojdbc7_g.jar) that you can use to print out logs that can then be used to debug. There is also Oracle support that can help you. We, on SO, can also help you if you provide the error message. Oracle wallets are commonly used so the error you're facing may already be known.

Comment: Does it print logs automatically to the console or does it need any other configuration?

Comment: It's based on the standard java util logging which you can configure to print to the console (standard output). Read this https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/11-2.pdf for more details.